# How to get all the campaigns related to a page by using Facebook Marketing Api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I used promote_pages endpoint (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/promote_pages/) to get all the promoted pages for an ads account.

To get more details for each page, I tried to put more parameters like (ad_campaign, engagement and category etc) but all the expected returned fields for ad_campaign is missing.

Sample request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/act_{{ads-account-id}}/promote_pages?fields=name,ad_campaign,engagement,category
```

(Also provided pagesAccessToken as BearerToken and pageAccessToken has **'public_profile', 'email','manage_pages', 'pages_messaging','publish_pages','ads_read','ads_management'** permissions and already have business integration done).

I received all the fields properly except campaign data as there are several campaigns running for each page already.

Please let me know how to achieve the campaign data returned for each page under an ads account. Thank you so much in advance.